# AWS Amplify Console deploy to different accounts

Tags: aws-amplify

I have 4 relevant AWS accounts (Services, Dev, QA, Prod). I intended Services to contain the CI/CD pipeline and deploy to the environment specific accounts. I setup a IAM user in each environment account to use for deployments. With AWS Amplify CLI I am able to set a different profile for each environment so that I can deploy to different accounts.

This works great but I wanted to use the Amplify Console as my CI/CD pipeline. It has the ability to setup different pipelines for different branches and is able to deploy the front-end to different accounts but requires a role to deploy the back-end. I can't find a way to set it up so that it can deploy the back-end to a different account but I am fairly new to it.

For now I will either use another CI/CD solution and make calls to the Amplify CLI or setup the Amplify pipeline in each environment account.

**Is there a way to setup the Amplify Console so that I can deploy the application back-end to a different account?**

Comment: did  you have any luck with this?

Comment: @niqui no, it doesn't seem to support it yet. I ran into many more issues with amplify and ended up switching to GCP Firebase.

Answer (score 5):

**Update on 19/11/2019**:

Using something like

```
 - echo -e "[default]\nregion={our-region}" > ~/.aws/config
 - amplifyPush --simple
```

on [backend phase of amplify.yml](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/build-settings.html) seems possible to manipulate the aws profile used by Amplify CLI and eventually deploy to different AWS accounts. At least by this way, I was able to deploy 2 different environments in different regions using a single instance of Amplify Console & AWS CodeCommit using the following instructions:

```
# Set a different region Amplify CLI 
- if [ "${AWS_BRANCH}" != "master" ]; then echo -e "[default]\nregion=${DEV_REGION}" > ~/.aws/config; fi
- '# Execute Amplify CLI with the helper script'
- amplifyPush --simple
```

Credits to this [post](https://dev.to/beavearony/personal-growth-with-git-flow-and-aws-amplify-console-part-3-1f6c)

---

This [doesn't seem possible](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli-toolchain/quickstart#using-the-aws-amplify-console) and there is an [open pull request looking for support](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-console/issues/64).

However, you can set up Amplify console in each AWS account and trigger independent deploys based on the branch:

- dev branch -> dev AWS account;
- master branch -> Production account;

and so on.

You can keep Amplify console set up in the same way by "[Save the build settings in your repository - Download the amplify.yml file and add it to the root of your repository (or root of the app folder for monorepos).](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/build-settings.html)".

Last, replication won't be required in case you (or someone else) uses AWS CodeCommit as a version control system but a [Cross-Account Access configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/cross-account.html) would be required.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. In the end, I had set up the Amplify console in each environment as you stated.